# PyQt new dialog with parameter

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

i've got issues trying to set up a new dialog from my main window passing a path argument, right now the dialog just flash and exit... I think the problem is where i show the windows but i can't figure out where i should put it!
In this XtractMainWindow.py file i set up the main window and get the path

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import ui_XtractMainWindow
import AndroidDialog
import sys

class XtractMainWindow(QMainWindow, ui_XtractMainWindow.Ui_XtractMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(XtractMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)

    self.androidXtractButton.clicked.connect(self.setAndroid)

def setAndroid(self):
    filename = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Open Directory", "/home")
    print filename
    dialog = AndroidDialog.AndroidDialog(str(filename))
    dialog.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form =  XtractMainWindow()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

This is the Dialog, in AndroidDialog.py file

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import csv
import sys
import Android_extractor
import ui_android_dialog

class AndroidDialog(QDialog, ui_android_dialog.Ui_androidDialog):
    def __init__(self, filename, parent=None):
        super(AndroidDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dialog = AndroidDialog.AndroidDialog(str(filename))
dialog.show()
```

Here you can see that you are saving the reference of dialog in a local variable. When `setAndroid(self)` is done with the execution, the `dialog` variable is collected (destroyed) by the garbage collector.

Please note that window exists as long as a reference to that window exists.

Do this:

```
self.dialog = AndroidDialog.AndroidDialog(str(filename))
self.dialog.show()
```

In this case `self.dialog` is a class member, that will not be collected or destroyed by the garbage collector.

Comment: You're right but the new dialog still don't show. I found that the metod to call is dialog.exec_() instead of show()

Comment: works fine here. The dialog does not disappear. You should accept the answer as it solves the problem, that may help someone in the future

Comment: Not sure what was wrong before, but now it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please note that `exec_()` has a special purpose to use it, this method blocks the execution of the code at the point where `exec_()` is called, but `show()` returns the control immediately after showing the window.